# Decorator with arg that returns the same function as passed

Tags: python, python-decorators

I want a decorator that adds is parameter as an attribute to the underlying function, then returns that function itself.  When I look in the module the function foo has been removed.  it does not even show up.

```
def addarg(x):
    def decorator(func):
        func.x = x
        return func

@addarg(17)
def foo():
    pass

print(foo.x)    # should print 17
```

Comment: add `return decorator` after `return func` in the same level of `def decorator(func):`

Comment: You need to `return decorator` from `addarg`. The decoration is equivalent to `foo = addarg(17)(foo)`.

Comment: The code above was a cut and paste fail on my part.  Even with the extra return included the pycharm debugger shows this function as not in the module, but within python "hasattr" shows that it is indeed there.  very confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on @Karl's comment, your code requires a single line to be added -

```
def addarg(x):
    def decorator(func):
        func.x = x
        return func
    return decorator # <-- Add this line

@addarg(17)
def foo():
    pass

print(foo.x)
```

That's all folks!

Comment: It is clearly a typo so in these cases an answer is not necessary since it does not contribute in the community so a comment is enough

Comment: I understand that it might be a trivial mistake for the more experienced but it was an entirely new concept for a novice like myself!! :D

Comment: okay, but was it necessary to publish an answer?, I think not because with your answer the community will have to make a greater effort to eliminate this type of question.

Comment: I am going to remove the question; as it stands it adds no value to the community.  My issue seems to stem from some discrepancy in the pycharm debugger display of the module's contents (in my original code I do have that return, somehow it causes the debugger to drop of function from the module (but "hasattr" shows it is still there.)

Comment: @DanOblinger You say that you are going to eliminate it but you do the opposite: marks as correct to the answer ...

Comment: I started to do so, StackOverflow warns that deleting my own questions is grounds for disabling my account.  (I am quite frustrated that there still is some subtle bug where the decorator seems to work in the body of the module, but not when accessed from outside?!?  if I can narrow my code to a reasonable question I will update my question, which was never about the typo in the first place).  sorry for my typo!